# Updating all rows in pandas DataFrame while iterating on single column

Tags: python, pandas, row, updating

I have a single column, ~100 row, multi-sheet DataFrame with all float64s. Sample data:

```
0
0.5
0.0.0.0
0.3.0.0
1.0.0.0
1.0.0.1
```

I'm looking to cast all the float64s to strings, to add a fixed prefix string and suffix string to each row, and to export the result as a .csv. Desired outcome:

```
"prefix 0 suffix"
"prefix 0.5 suffix"
"prefix 0.0.0.0 suffix"
"prefix 0.3.0.0 suffix"
"prefix 1.0.0.0 suffix"
"prefix 1.0.0.1 suffix"
```

The first stumbling block is with df = df.applymap(str), when I look at the objects within df after this mapping, I still see floats.

The second stumbling block is in the iteration - I can't seem to update the value of each item with the string prefix and string suffix. When I look at the output file, I see the original df, completely untouched, all floats.

```
import pandas as pd
path = "magic.xlsx"

for x in range(8):
    file = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=0, index_col=0, header=None)
    df = pd.DataFrame(file)

    # How should I change all items to strings?
    df = df.applymap(str)

    # How do I get each item to update?
    for item in df.index:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            df.at[i,0] = "prefix" + x + "suffix"
        else:
            df.at[i,0] = "prefix" + x.astype(str) + "suffix"

    df.to_csv('new.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

What I'm looking to do is simple, but I think I'm getting tripped up on a lack of a column name when I look at other examples.

Comment: when you say 'can't get it to work', what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't get the expected behavior other posts suggest I should get. For example, with the applymap, when I go to print the objects in df, I still have floats and not strings. Similarly, I don't get updated objects in df after adding a prefix and suffix, even when the string changes themselves are valid.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data in text? And desired output

Comment: Done, thanks for helping me clarify.